# How to find the sum of the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, telescopic-series

$$\frac{1}{1.3} + \frac{7}{1.3.5} + \frac{17}{1.3.5.7} + \frac{31}{1.3.5.7.9} +...... upto \space 10 \space terms$$

I found the nth term of the equation but don't know how to proceed from there?

$$ T_n = \frac{2n^2 -1 }{1.3.5.7...(2n-1)(2n+1)}$$

Comment: Just use a calculator if you want to compute the sum of $10$ terms only.

Comment: You've written up to 10 terms - does this mean you're trying to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{10} \frac{2n^2 -1 }{1.3.5.7...(2n-1)(2n+1)}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [double factorial notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial), this is
$$\sum^{10}_{n=1}\frac{2n^2-1}{(2n+1)!!}.$$ But $$2n^2-1=\frac{(2n-1)(2n+1)-1}2,$$
and that means $$\frac{2n^2-1}{(2n+1)!!}=\frac12\left(\frac1{(2n-3)!!}-\frac1{(2n+1)!!}\right),$$ i.e. we have a telescoping series, so
\begin{align}\sum^{10}_{n=1}\frac{2n^2-1}{(2n+1)!!}&=\frac12\left(\frac1{(-1)!!}+\frac1{1!!}-\frac1{19!!}-\frac1{21!!}\right)=\frac12\left(2-\frac1{654729075}-\frac1{13749310575
}\right)\\&=1-\frac1{1249937325}.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I actually wrote 2n^2 - 1 in that way, just didn't separate it in the telescopic series, was very stupid of me. Thank you again sir.

Comment: @Avinash Bhawnani I had to edit it to correct a mistake.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that. I just was shocked how I missed that and was happy with the method only. Thanks again. :)